# Facebook like button, site name is not clickable on Facebook page

Tags: facebook

I'm using the Facebook like button, and while my like'd URL shows up correctly on the site and is clickable, the site URL after the 'on' isn't clickable.

Example on Facebook: (bold is clickable)

> Philip likes **Fun & Fresh: Cafe Gitane** on www.example.com. · Comment · Like

However, the 'example.com' is supposed to be clickable as well. I have seen other sites (like theonion.com) do it. How can I do it?

Here are my meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=$title?>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="www.example.com"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/example-bw.jpg"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="example"/>

<?
if ($_GET[fb]=="g" ){echo"<meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"www.example.com%2Fgoingout.php%3Ffid%3D$fid&fb=g\"/>";
?>
```

The URL linter is getting all of the information above. However it's not displaying a 'site URL' property.

I have tried writing the og:site name as `http://www, www,`, whatever. Nothing makes it clickable.

Here's a weird twist: if I enter the og:site_name as example.com then the og:site name displays like that (it shows up on Facebook with visible `<a></a>` tags around it), but it's clickable AND there's a separate property shown in the linter as 'site URL' which doesn't otherwise display. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

og:site_name is supposed to be the "name" of the site, not the url. If you enter Example as the site name the link will work. What you are experiencing is either the way facebook intended it or a bug. Either are likely. I know that if you use text not in url format the link will appear, but you might also want to try just not including the og:site_name tag. The default behavior I think is to just display the site domain name if no site_name is found.

Comment: i just tried 'Example' as the site name, and went to the URL linter and still does not show example as clickable in the linter. also tested on the site and not clickable. very odd stuff. do you think this is related to my setting the og:type as 'article'? it is an article on a website.

Comment: That is possible. Article is a special type of open graph item. All other items represent facebook pages where as the article type does not. There are a number of things you cannot do with the article type that you can do with the other types such as communicate with people who have liked this. I would suggest 1) searching the facebook bug reports to see if you can find this or 2) creating a bug report.